# Git alias para o nome do branch atual

Tags: git

No meu trabalho é muito comum alternar entre feature branches e stage/develop branches várias vezes durante o dia. E muitas dessas vezes eu preciso escrever ou usar tab pra completar o nome do branch mesmo estando dentro dele. Eu queria algo que agisse de forma semelhante a um `this` em programação: uma referência ao nome do branch atual.

**Problema:**

```
$ git checkout -b feature/nova-feature
// aqui eu trabalho na nova feature ate ficar ok
$ git push origin feature/nova-feature (*)
$ git checkout stage && git merge feature/nova-feature (*)
$ git push origin stage (*)
$ git checkout feature/outra-feature
// trabalho em mais alguma coisa
$ git push origin feature/outra-feature (*)
$ git checkout stage && git merge feature/outra-feature (*)
$ git push origin stage (*)

 etc
```

Em 8 interações com o `git` eu tive que escrever 6 vezes o nome do branch em que eu estou (em 3 branches diferentes).

**O que eu já tenho hoje** no meu .gitconfig

```
[alias]
    mg = merge --no-ff --no-edit
    mc = commit -a --no-edit
    df = "!git diff --color | diff-so-fancy"
    ck = "!git checkout $1 && git pull origin $1"
    gr = "!git branch | !grep $1"
    msp = "!git ck $1 && git mg $2 && git push origin $1"
```

`ck`, `gr` e `msp` são alias que me permitem escrever uma vez só o nome do branch quando vou concatenar.

**O que eu queria:**

```
$ git checkout -b feature/nova-feature
// aqui eu trabalho na nova feature ate ficar ok
$ git push origin this
$ git checkout stage && git merge this
$ git push origin this
$ git checkout feature/outra-feature
// trabalho em mais alguma coisa
$ git push origin this
$ git checkout stage && git merge this
$ git push origin this
```

De forma que eu pudesse criar `alias` pra essas ações mais comuns e que funcionem em qualquer branch, sem precisar escrever o nome. Tem jeito?

Comment: veja se isso te ajuda https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/1v16qc/how_do_i_reference_the_current_branch_in_a_git/

Comment: Isto pode ajudar um pouco no seu fluxo: se quiser voltar para a branch anterior, você pode usar `git checkout -`

Comment: Perfeito, vou apagar meus comentários daqui então, pra não deixar bagunça na sua postagem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ricardo você pode usar os alias da seguinte forma:

[alias]

**#Pega seu branch**

branch-name = "!git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"

**#Publica seu branch**

publish = "!git push -u origin $(git branch-name)"

**#Deleta a versão remota do seu branch**

unpublish = "!git push origin :$(git branch-name)"

**Dessa forma você usaria assim:**

```
$ git checkout -b feature/nova-feature
// aqui eu trabalho na nova feature ate ficar ok
$ git publish
$ git unpublish
```

De uma olhada nos alias utilizados neste [link](https://gist.github.com/robmiller/6018582) do @robmiller usuário do github, que acredito que você conseguira implementar um workflow de trabalho bem produtivo.

Comment: opa, não resolveu 100% não mas acho que me levou pro lugar certo, vou ver aqui e atualizo

Comment: Tranquilo Ricardo, acredito que desta forma da para você reduzir bastante a digitação e mudar o fluxo seu para ficar mais pratico :)

Comment: Adicionei o formato que fiz funcionar, ficou massa. Valeu!

Answer (score 4):

**Solução Encontrada**

seguindo os passos da resposta do Diego Garcia, cheguei à seguinte configuração, que me permite nunca precisar escrever o nome do branch atual:

```
[alias]
    branch-name = "!git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
    mg = merge --no-ff --no-edit
    ck = "!git checkout $1 && git pull origin $1"
    cm = "!BRANCH=$(git branch-name); git ck $1 && git mg $BRANCH"
```

Forma de usar concatenando os aliases (pra todos os outros comandos que precisarem desse mesmo padrão, basta usar o formato do alias `cm` acima)

```
$ git cm stage
```

Equivale a:

```
$ git checkout stage && git pull origin stage && git merge branch-atual --no-ff --no-edit
```

Comment: Ficou show Ricardo :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode controlar isso através da configuração push.default.

A opção que você quer é a current.

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Então você pode usar apenas `git push` e vai conseguir esse comportamento.

Para ver outras opções possíveis consulte o man page do git-config ([ou clique aqui](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html))